# How do you plot survival functions for specific values of covariates in SAS?

Tags: data-visualization, sas, survival

Suppose I do the following:

```
    proc phreg data = new; 
         model time*censor(0) = x y;
    run;
```

Also suppose $x$ is a binary variable and $y$ is a continuous variable. How would I plot the survival function for $x = 1$ and $y = 100$ (for example) in SAS?

Answer (score 1):

From the help files of phreg (assuming neither X or Y in your example are time varying):

```
ods graphics on;
    proc phreg data=Myeloma plots(overlay)=survival;
    model Time*VStatus(0)=LogBUN HGB;
    baseline covariates=Inrisks out=Pred1 survival=_all_ / rowid=Id;
    run;
    ods graphics off;
```

The COVARIATES= option in the BASELINE statement specifies the data set that contains the
set of covariates of interest. The PLOTS= option in the PROC PHREG statement creates the survivor
plot. The OVERLAY suboption overlays the two curves in the same plot. If the OVERLAY
suboption is not specified, each curve is displayed in a separate plot. The ROWID= option in the
BASELINE statement specifies that the values of the variable Id in the COVARIATES= data set be
used to identify the curves in the plot. The SURVIVAL=*ALL* option in the BASELINE statement
requests that the estimated survivor function, standard error, and lower and upper confidence limits
for the survivor function be output into the SAS data set specified in the OUT= option.
The survival Plot (Output 64.8.1) contains two curves, one for each of row of covariates in the data
set Inrisks.

Comment: That is what I did. But it seems that the survival functions stops at 0.9. So it doesn't go all the way down to 0.

Comment: I'm assuming its because your data is censored after 10% of the data experiences the event?